# Warning: Set-Cookie header was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but come from a cross site response

Tags: web, session, cookies, same-origin-policy

I have a server running ([example.io](https://example.io/)). If I am running my backend as well as frontend in [example.io](https://example.io/) but with different ports, everything works. If I am using localhost for my frontend and running my backend on [example.io](https://example.io/), I get the warning message I set in the title, which I think it means cookies are not saved (I can't log in).

But why? Isn't same domain and different ports consider to be different and cross-site? What is the difference if I am using localhost? Why cookies are saved if I'm running both my frontend and backend with different ports in [example.io](https://example.io/), but not if I am running my frontend on localhost? Also, what can I do to fix this so I could save cookies on my localhost?

Thank you so much in advance.

I have my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to my frontend host and port and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to true. I really have no idea why running my frontend on localhost doesn't save the cookies.